# Subsonic 3 + LINQ bug

Tags: subsonic, subsonic3

A weird bug with Subsonic 3.0.0.3

Using - as an example - AdventureWorksLT DB

When I run this code

I get null for gname (although name gets the value ok)
And w is 0 instead of the value in the 1st row
[If I change select new MyData to just select MyData - it works OK]

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {

        var q = from g in Product.All()
                select new MyData{
                    gname = g.Name,
                    name = g.Name,
                    w = g.Weight.Value
                };
        var list00 = q.Take(1).ToList();
        Console.WriteLine(list00[0].gname);
    }
}
public class MyData {
    public string gname { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public decimal w { get; set; }
}
```

Any ideas what is wrong

Thanks

Mike

Answer (score 1):

I think there's currently some bugs with projection: http://groups.google.com/group/subsonicproject/browse_thread/thread/2b569539b7f67a34/6f703e0e4ce15141?lnk=gst&q=projection#6f703e0e4ce15141

Answer (score 1):

Yes, i think there's a bug when subsonic try to project into new typed class (non anonymous and non source class).

Your query will work fine if you do like this

```
var q = from g in Product.All()
       select new{
            gname = g.Name,
            name = g.Name,
            w = g.Weight.Value
       };
```

or if you do like this

```
var q = from g in Product.All()
       select g;
```

As a solution, please fork my repository (http://github.com/funky81/SubSonic-3.0/commit/aa7a9c1b564b2667db7fbd41e09ab72f5d58dcdb). You can see my source code and apply it into your subsonic code.